# Printed representation of list

Tags: python

I want to format a list into a string in this way:
`[1,2,3] => '1 2 3'`. How to do this?
Is there any customizable formatter in Python as Common Lisp format?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
' '.join(str(i) for i in your_list)
```

Comment: That would be great ... if it worked !!! If you list contains anything that's not a string, this line will fail with the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: '{0} {1} {2}'.format(your_list) solves the problem too. The point is that you need to do join on a separator. I cannot possibly believe that OP needs actual representation of [1,2,3] list.

Comment: In my opinion, for the sake of correctness, and for beginners that will seek answer on this website, you should always post code that works, or at least say what need to be done to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

```
' '.join(str(i) for i in your_list)
```

First, convert any element into a string, then join them into a unique string.

Comment: @Nadia: Yes, but that is discouraged, list comprehensions are the recommended way.